# SQL window function with a where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to correlate two types of events for users.  I want to see all event "B"s along with the most recent event "A" for that user prior to the "A" event.  How would one accomplish this?  In particular, I'm trying to do this in Postgres.

I was hoping it was possible to use a "where" clause in a window function, in which case I could essentially do a LAG() with a "where event='A'", but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Any recommendations?

Data example:

```
|user |time|event|
|-----|----|-----|
|Alice|1   |A    |
|Bob  |2   |A    |
|Alice|3   |A    |
|Alice|4   |B    |
|Bob  |5   |B    |
|Alice|6   |B    |
```

Desired result:

```
|user |event_b_time|last_event_a_time|
|-----|------------|-----------------|
|Alice|4           |3                |
|Bob  |5           |2                |
|Alice|6           |3                |
```

Answer (score 41):

Just tried Gordon's approach using PostgreSQL 9.5.4, and it complained that

> FILTER is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions

which means using `lag()` with `FILTER` is not allowed. So I modified Gordon's query using `max()`, a different window frame, and CTE:

```sql
WITH subq AS (
  SELECT
    "user", event, time as event_b_time,
    max(time) FILTER (WHERE event = 'A') OVER (
      PARTITION BY "user"
      ORDER BY time
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) AS last_event_a_time
  FROM events
  ORDER BY time
)
SELECT
  "user", event_b_time, last_event_a_time
FROM subq
WHERE event = 'B';
```

Verified that this works with PostgreSQL 9.5.4.

Thanks to Gordon for the `FILTER` trick!

Comment: Excellent trick with replacing `lag()` with `max()` and `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` to avoid psql `FILTER is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions`!!

Comment: This is super cool. Works great and it's fast. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

There is not need for window functions here. Just find all `B` events, and for each one of them, find the most recent `A` of the same user via a subquery. Something like that should do it:

```
SELECT
    "user",
    time AS event_b_time,
    (SELECT time AS last_event_a_time
     FROM t t1
     WHERE "user"=t.user AND event='A' AND time<t.time
     ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM t
WHERE event='B';
```

I assume that the table is called `t` (I used it twice).

Comment: How would the performance of this query compare to a query using the lag() function?

Comment: As Gordon said, this approach is probably faster.