# Take first, second, third ... last value and selecting rows (Window function with filter and lag)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.6

I would like to perform a window function with a filter clause, for example:

```
LAG("date", 1) FILTER (WHERE type='A') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC) AS "A_lag_1"
```

However, Postgres doesn't support this operation but I cant determine how else do it. Details below

**Challange**

Input `tab_A`:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | type | date |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | A    |   30 |
|  1 | A    |   25 |
|  1 | A    |   20 |
|  1 | B    |   29 |
|  1 | B    |   28 |
|  1 | B    |   21 |
|  1 | C    |   24 |
|  1 | C    |   22 |
+----+------+------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | type | date | A_lag_1 | A_lag_2 | B_lag_1 | B_lag_2 | C_lag_1 | C_lag_2 |
+----+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | A    |   30 |      25 |      20 |      29 |      28 |      24 |      22 |
|  1 | A    |   25 |      20 |         |         |         |      24 |      22 |
|  1 | A    |   20 |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  1 | B    |   29 |      25 |      20 |      28 |      21 |      24 |      22 |
|  1 | B    |   28 |      25 |      20 |      21 |         |      24 |      22 |
|  1 | B    |   21 |      20 |         |         |         |      24 |      22 |
|  1 | C    |   24 |      20 |         |      21 |         |      22 |         |
|  1 | C    |   22 |      20 |         |      21 |         |         |         |
+----+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

In words:

- For each row select all rows which occurred before it (see `date` column)
- Then for each `type` ('A', 'B', 'C') put the most recent `date` in `A_lag_1` and the second the most recent (by date) value in `A_lag_2` for `type` 'A', and `B_lag_1`, `B_lag_2` for 'B' etc.

The above example is quite simplified, in my real use case there will be a lot more `id` values, more lag column iterations `A_lag_X` and types.

**Posible solution**
This challenge seems a perfect fit for a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-window.html) as I want to keep the same number of rows `tab_A` and append information which is related to the row but in the past.

So constructing it using a window function ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d566e2/4)):

```
SELECT
  id, type, "date",
  LAG("date", 1) FILTER (WHERE type='A') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC) AS "A_lag_1",
  LAG("date", 2) FILTER (WHERE type='A') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC) AS "A_lag_2",
  LAG("date", 1) FILTER (WHERE type='B') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC) AS "B_lag_1",
  LAG("date", 2) FILTER (WHERE type='B') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC) AS "B_lag_2",
  LAG("date", 1) FILTER (WHERE type='C') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC) AS "C_lag_1",
  LAG("date", 2) FILTER (WHERE type='C') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC) AS "C_lag_2"
FROM tab_A
```

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR: FILTER is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions
>   Position: 30

Although this error is referenced in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) I cant determine another way of doing it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Other SO questions:

- [1.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39599973/1110328) This answer relies on using an aggregate function such as `max`. However, this won't work when trying to retrieve the 2nd last row, 3rd last row etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `FILTER` clause does work with aggregate functions, I decided to [write my own](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xaggr.html).

```
----- N = 1
-- State transition function
-- agg_state: the current state, el: new element
create or replace function lag_agg_sfunc_1(agg_state point, el float)
    returns point
    immutable
    language plpgsql
    as $$
declare
    i integer;
    stored_value float;
begin
    i := agg_state[0];
    stored_value := agg_state[1];

    i := i + 1; -- First row i=1
    if i = 1 then
        stored_value := el;
    end if;
    return point(i, stored_value);
end;
$$;

-- Final function
--DROP FUNCTION lag_agg_ffunc_1(point) CASCADE;
create or replace function lag_agg_ffunc_1(agg_state point)
    returns float
    immutable
    strict
    language plpgsql
    as $$
begin
  return agg_state[1];
end;
$$;

-- Aggregate function
drop aggregate if exists lag_agg_1(double precision);
create aggregate lag_agg_1 (float) (
    sfunc = lag_agg_sfunc_1,
    stype = point,
    finalfunc = lag_agg_ffunc_1,
    initcond = '(0,0)'
);


----- N = 2
-- State transition function
-- agg_state: the current state, el: new element
create or replace function lag_agg_sfunc_2(agg_state point, el float)
    returns point
    immutable
    language plpgsql
    as $$
declare
    i integer;
    stored_value float;
begin
    i := agg_state[0];
    stored_value := agg_state[1];

    i := i + 1; -- First row i=1
    if i = 2 then
        stored_value := el;
    end if;
    return point(i, stored_value);
end;
$$;

-- Final function
--DROP FUNCTION lag_agg_ffunc_2(point) CASCADE;
create or replace function lag_agg_ffunc_2(agg_state point)
    returns float
    immutable
    strict
    language plpgsql
    as $$
begin
  return agg_state[1];
end;
$$;

-- Aggregate function
drop aggregate if exists lag_agg_2(double precision);
create aggregate lag_agg_2 (float) (
    sfunc = lag_agg_sfunc_2,
    stype = point,
    finalfunc = lag_agg_ffunc_2,
    initcond = '(0,0)'
);
```

You can use the above aggregate functions `lag_agg_1` and `lag_agg_2` with the window expression in the original question:

```
SELECT
  id, type, "date",
  NULLIF(lag_agg_1("date") FILTER (WHERE type='A') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) AS "A_lag_1",
  NULLIF(lag_agg_2("date") FILTER (WHERE type='A') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) AS "A_lag_2",
  NULLIF(lag_agg_1("date") FILTER (WHERE type='B') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) AS "B_lag_1",
  NULLIF(lag_agg_2("date") FILTER (WHERE type='B') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) AS "B_lag_2",
  NULLIF(lag_agg_1("date") FILTER (WHERE type='C') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) AS "C_lag_1",
  NULLIF(lag_agg_2("date") FILTER (WHERE type='C') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) AS "C_lag_2"
FROM tab_A
ORDER BY id ASC, type, "date" DESC
```

This executes reasonably quickly compared to the other options. Some things that could be improved:

- I couldn't determine how to work with null values properly and so at the end fudging the result by converting all 0's to NULLs. This will cause problems in certain situations
- I have just copied and pasted the functions for each lag_X as I couldn't determine how to parameterise this

Any help with the above would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution using a lateral join ([fiddle](http://%20%20http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d566e2/51/0)):

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.type,
    a."date",
    c.nn_row,
    c.type,
    c."date" as "date_joined"
FROM tab_A AS a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        type,
        "date",
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id, type ORDER BY id ASC, "date" DESC) as nn_row
    FROM tab_A AS b
    WHERE a."date" > b."date"
) AS c on true
WHERE c.nn_row <= 5
```

This creates a long table like:

```
+----+------+------+--------+------+-------------+
| id | type | date | nn_row | type | date_joined |
+----+------+------+--------+------+-------------+
|  1 | A    |   30 |      1 | A    |          25 |
|  1 | A    |   30 |      2 | A    |          20 |
|  1 | A    |   30 |      1 | B    |          29 |
|  1 | A    |   30 |      2 | B    |          28 |
|  1 | A    |   30 |      3 | B    |          21 |
|  1 | A    |   30 |      1 | C    |          24 |
|  1 | A    |   30 |      2 | C    |          22 |
|  1 | A    |   25 |      1 | A    |          20 |
|  1 | A    |   25 |      1 | B    |          21 |
|  1 | A    |   25 |      1 | C    |          24 |
|  1 | A    |   25 |      2 | C    |          22 |
|  1 | B    |   29 |      1 | A    |          25 |
|  1 | B    |   29 |      2 | A    |          20 |
|  1 | B    |   29 |      1 | B    |          28 |
|  1 | B    |   29 |      2 | B    |          21 |
|  1 | B    |   29 |      1 | C    |          24 |
|  1 | B    |   29 |      2 | C    |          22 |
|  1 | B    |   28 |      1 | A    |          25 |
|  1 | B    |   28 |      2 | A    |          20 |
|  1 | B    |   28 |      1 | B    |          21 |
|  1 | B    |   28 |      1 | C    |          24 |
|  1 | B    |   28 |      2 | C    |          22 |
|  1 | B    |   21 |      1 | A    |          20 |
|  1 | C    |   24 |      1 | A    |          20 |
|  1 | C    |   24 |      1 | B    |          21 |
|  1 | C    |   24 |      1 | C    |          22 |
|  1 | C    |   22 |      1 | A    |          20 |
|  1 | C    |   22 |      1 | B    |          21 |
+----+------+------+--------+------+-------------+
```

After which you can pivot to the desired output.

However, this worked for me on a small sample but on the full table Postgres ran out of disk space (even though I have 50GB available):

> ERROR: could not write to hash-join temporary file: No space left on device

I have posted this solution here as it might work for others who have smaller tables

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

```
SELECT
dt.* ,
(SELECT MAX(b.dateVAL)  FROM tab_A  b WHERE b.type = 'A' AND dt.A_lag_1 >  b.dateVAL  ) AS "A_lag_2",
(SELECT MAX(b.dateVAL)  FROM tab_A  b WHERE b.type = 'B' AND dt.B_lag_1 >  b.dateVAL  ) AS "B_lag_2" ,
(SELECT MAX(b.dateVAL)  FROM tab_A  b WHERE b.type = 'C' AND dt.C_lag_1 >  b.dateVAL  ) AS "C_lag_2"
FROM
(
SELECT
  a.id, a.type, a.dateVAL,
 (SELECT MAX(b.dateVAL)  FROM tab_A  b WHERE b.type = 'A' AND a.dateVAL >  b.dateVAL  )  as A_lag_1,
 (SELECT MAX(b.dateVAL)  FROM tab_A  b WHERE b.type = 'B' AND a.dateVAL >  b.dateVAL  )  as B_lag_1,
 (SELECT MAX(b.dateVAL)  FROM tab_A  b WHERE b.type = 'C' AND a.dateVAL >  b.dateVAL  )  as C_lag_1
FROM tab_A a
)   dt
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/92a74/42) link. this may not be the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am testing it now to see if it works :)

Comment: This method works on a sample but takes a very long time to execute on the full table (I left it running for 20h and never finished)